# Hibernate Fetch is not longer sub-type of Join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, fetch

I'm using Hibernate 5.2.10 with dynamic criteria and find out that Fetch is not longer assignable to Join.

In the next example, I need to fetch group data in the same query, but I also need to use the group's field for sorting or restriction.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<GroupAssignment> query = cb.createQuery(GroupAssignment.class);

Root<GroupAssignment> root = query.from(GroupAssignment.class);
SingularAttributeJoin<GroupAssignment, Group> groupFetch = (SingularAttributeJoin<GroupAssignment, Group>) root.fetch(GroupAssignment_.group, JoinType.LEFT);
query.orderBy(cb.asc(groupFetch.get(Group_.title)));
```

I have manually cast Fetch to the SingularAttributeJoin and after that, I can use get method for the ordering purpose, but I'm looking for the right way how I can do that **without casting manually**.

GroupAssignment class:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "group_assignment")
public class GroupAssignment {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "group_assignment_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", nullable = false)
  private Group group;

  //other fields, getters and setters
}
```

GroupAssignment_ class:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(GroupAssignment.class)
public abstract class GroupAssignment_ {
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<GroupAssignment, Integer> id;
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<GroupAssignment, Group> group;
}
```

Group class:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "navigation_group")
public class Group {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "group_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "title")
  private String title;

  //other fields, getters and setters
}
```

Group_ class:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Group.class)
public abstract class Group_ {
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<Group, Integer> id;
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<Group, String> title;
}
```

Comment: Can you put the code where you try to cast?

Comment: It is already present in the original description (casting to the SingularAttributeJoin)

Comment: Is this `CriteriaBuilder` the Hibernate-own CriteriaBuilder? Because there is a `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder` which is quite well documented

Comment: Yes, it is javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder

Comment: Ok, good. Is it possible to post the Group, GroupAssignment, Group_ and GroupAssignment_ classes?

Comment: The method `get(String)` you try to invoke from `SingularAttributeJoin<GroupAssignment, Group>` is defined in `javax.persistence.criteria.Path<>`. Is it possible to cast for `Path<Group>` instead?

Comment: I don't want to have any manual type casting. I'll update the main description with classes shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that correct way would be next:

```
query.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(GroupAssignment_.group).get(Group_.title)));
```

So using multiple call to `.get` method you can go as deep as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that javax.persistence.criteria.FetchParent may solve your problem:

```
FetchParent<GroupAssignment, Group> groupFetch = root.fetch(GroupAssignment_.group, JoinType.LEFT);
```

Comment: I don't see how **FetchParent** can solve my issue. It is actually a superclass of **Fetch**, so it has even less public methods then Fetch...

Comment: You are right.  I had to do almost the same, using the FetchParent and manually casting to Join too, but later in the code, so I missed it when I first checked to see how I did. Sorry.